# Dependent variable has no variance error in logit regression

Tags: logistic, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, dependent-variable

I m running a logit regression with over 90,000 observations. However the case when dependent variable =1 , is only 115 observations as per the data, the rest are 0. The Eviews software shows "dependent variable has no variance" error. Why is this so? Isn't it normal that the event did not happen for the rest of the observations and hence the binary dependent variable has more observations with 0 value than 1. Can someone advise?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clearly wrong: your data has a non-zero variance, though it is clearly imbalanced. What thus means for you? First, 115 positive samples are not much, if you can it might be wise to gather more data. Second, you need to consider how to deal with it. You can find a lot of discussion on this problem in many threads tagged as [unbalanced-classes](/questions/tagged/unbalanced-classes) that we have.